# How to create a custom html form with Twillio Send Grid

Tags: sendgrid

I am trying to create a contact intake form on SendGrid. However, it seems to only want to let me do an iframe which renders weird on an existing site. Is it possible to customize the HTML of the intake form so that I can more seamlessly embed the form into the site?

I looked around the docs but it appears the only options are the iframe and separate longing page, neither of which are what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own form that `POST`s the data to your back-end and then use the [Add Contact API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact) to create the contact.